# Linux Terminal Shortcuts

Tags: linux

Is there any way to make "shortcuts" to programs on the linux mint terminal?

I'm trying to make a shortcut to sublime text, and I want to write something like "Sublime" and it opens automatically, is there any way to do this? I'm not finding it on google

Comment: this question isn't about programming, you should post it on an other stackexhange website such as superuser

Comment: @Antzi I though I could post this on Stack, sorry about that

Comment: You should put the directory where `sublime` is installed in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a symlink to the Sublime program:

```
ln -s /opts/sublime/sublime /home/ash/sublime
```

This assumes that your Sublime program be located at `/opts/sublime/sublime` and that you want the symlink to be located in your `/home` folder.

Now if you cd to your directory, you will see the symlink there:

```
cd /home/ash/
ls -l

/home/ash/sublime -> /opts/sublime/sublime
```

And if you want to run Sublime from your home folder you can just type:

```
sublime
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `alias` from bash:

```
alias sublime=/your/path/to/sublime/executable
```

And add the above line to your `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.bash_profile`

Comment: Also, you'd have to add that line to your $HOME/.bashrc file for it to work every time. Otherwise, the alias will disappear when you close the terminal.